# jQuery Checkbox Submit

Tags: php, jquery

I'm looking to auto submit when a specific **checkbox** is checked.

I need it to pass to ajax.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name=<?php echo("$newseo"); ?>]").click(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    var favorite=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'check_favorite.php',
            data:'id= ' + id + '&favorite='+favorite
        });
    }
    });
});
```

But I just can't seem to get it to work,

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Comment: Just for kicks, in your jQuery selector for the checkbox, select it by ID rather than by name.  `$('#yourcheckboxid')`

Comment: what does your html look like?

Comment: HTML: <input name="<?php echo("$newseo"); ?>" value="yes" type="checkbox" id="<?php echo("$newseo"); ?">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, this should do it. Your AJAX looks fine. I put together a JSFiddle to demonstrate.

```
$("input[name=TestCheck]:checked").live('click', function(e) {
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    var favorite=$(this).val();
        alert(id + " - " + favorite);
       // Post here ...
       $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'check_favorite.php',
        data: {id: id, favorite: favorite}
    });

});
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4GQ6K/1/

I don't really like using obtrusive JavaScript and inputting PHP into JavaScript like that but there is no reason it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#my_checkbox').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#my_form').submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your server side code[php] to set a id or a class to your specific checkbox. Then bind a click event to the given class name, e.g.

php code sets a class named `.sCheckBx`.

then on document.ready bind your event :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sCheckBx").click(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    var favorite=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'check_favorite.php',
            data:'id= ' + id + '&favorite='+favorite
        });
    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("checkboxId").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.is(":checked")){
      var id=$this.attr('id');
      var favorite=$this.val();
      $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'check_favorite.php',
            data:'id= ' + id + '&favorite='+favorite
        });
     } 
    }
  });
});
```